# Logic behind modular function

Tags: c++, int, void, modular

I do not understand why mysteryfunction(y) will equate to 40
when i int mysteryFunction(int, int =2). Anyone can explain to me?

Best, MM

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int mysteryFunction (int, int = 2);

int main()
{
    int x = 10, y = 20;
    cout << mysteryFunction (y); 

}

int mysteryFunction (int x, int y)
{
   return x * y;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the declaration of`mysteryFunction()` the second parameter is assigned a default value of `2`, so if you call it only with one argument the second argument `y` will be `2`.

Hence doing `mysteryFunction(20)` is basically the same as doing `mysteryFunction(20, 2)`, which according to your code should return 20 * 2 = 40.

You may have been confused by the fact that the variable you pass to `mysteryFunction()` as its first argument is named `y`, same as the second parameter in its definition. However, those are completely different variables. In fact, it doesn't matter how you call them, only the position of arguments/parameters matters (along with their type if you take function overloading into account).

Answer (score 1):

They will assume by default that y will be 2, thus when you fill in int x, it'll automatically take in (x,2).

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration for `mysteryFunction` you give a default value of 2 to the second argument. Then you call it with only 1 argument so the default gets used for the second argument. So y=20 and 20 * 2 = 40. Don't mix up variable names. The `x` and `y` in `main` have nothing to do with `x` and `y` in `mysteryFunction`